# Merge 4 Meshes and Textures to a Single Mesh With One Texture File

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have a file containing 4 meshes with 4 separate textures that are placed together and form a complete tree. How can I join these 4 meshes and Textures to make a single mesh with a single texture in it?

I found some tutorials on Youtube but because I have many of these files, I prefer to find an automated way that is faster and doesn't need my direct intervention!

[Download .Blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ROPg0Mc2QoNMaFPfVZsyfkLwQVMEOI8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've actually made this, but it requires ImageMagic to install as a module inside Blender, it's pretty hard

Comment: so It has no easy solution to follow? because I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: The info that you gave is misleading. The link provides only one OBJ file + 4 PNG image files. It's not a blend file ;-) And there is only one mesh, not 4. It looks like a photo-scanned twig. The 4 images are 4 UDIM tiles. If you want to have only one image you can create a new UV map and bake the texture.

Comment: @Blunder
I'm sorry if the explanation was confusing to you. but I'm pretty sure the file have 4 meshes grouped together. I have used Rhino 3D for years and in this software when I open the file, it contains 4 meshes. I attached images below:
https://ibb.co/VS3QSWm
https://ibb.co/Jj9L1Bh
yes I want One image file for textures but I don't want to do it manually because I have so many trees like that and if I want to do it manually it take too long!

Comment: I've just double-checked that there is only one mesh when you import the *.obj file into Blender. The mesh has no loose parts but has 4 materials. Each material uses just one UDIM tile (=one image). If you separate the mesh by materials the result looks like your screenshot (=4 objects, each with a different material). Since Blender supports UDIMs, you can get the job done with just one material. With texture baking, you can create a single image from the 4 tiles. But I guess you need to write a script if you don't want to do this many times manually.

Comment: thanks for your guidance.